# Cubemap rotation

Tags: unity, shaders, unity-shader-graph, cubemap

I have a skybox with stars cubemap
So, how can I rotate stars cubemap on Z axis using "Rotate About Axis"?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what rotation you're describing. Consider adding a diagram to your question to illustrate?

Comment: What is incomprehensible in the rotation of Skybox?!!!!!

Comment: A skybox has as many degrees of rotational freedom as any other object. If you're trying to simulate motion of stars as observed from the north pole, you'd rotate around one axis. If your observer is at the equator, you'd use a different rotation axis. If you want to simulate an observer at an arbitrary latitude, you'd use another axis yet. It also depends on how the contents of your skybox texture are set up. (eg. is Polaris in the center of the y+ face, or is your skybox oriented relative to the ecliptic plane instead?) This is why a diagram helps make your situation unambiguous.

Comment: I want to simulate motion of stats. But how can I simulate the axis by float like set the float 90° to make it rotate to right?

Comment: And thanks for the explanation

Comment: To whose right? What axis are we rotating around?

Comment: around the Y axis

Comment: So what is the reference to "when it is zero it rotates to the left **on the z axis**" in your question, if it is only ever a y-axis rotation you want? Try editing to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple skybox shader graph that allows you to rotate a cubemap about the y axis by an angle you provide in degrees:

[image: Rotating cubemap shader graph]

The `Axis = (0, 1, 0)` is what makes it rotate around the y axis. You can change this to a different axis, or even chain two of these nodes if you'd like to combine rotation due to time of day with rotation due to the observer's latitude.

Comment: Thank you, I have done this before, but this is not what I wanted, but I will implement it until I find out the way I want it.

Comment: This is why I wrote comments asking you to clarify what you wanted. The more specific you can be, the better your chances of getting an answer that delivers what you really want. Try explaining, in detail and with diagrams or screenshots, how the behaviour you observe with this graph differs from what you want.

Comment: After trying I think I will let it like that

Comment: But I'm still facing the problem of consistency of the cubemap with moon shape

Comment: If this answer solved your problem with rotating a cubemap, you can click the checkmark icon in the top left to mark it as Accepted. If it did not, you'll need to edit your question to clarify. You have a separate question about the moon, so we will not address that here.

Comment: Thank you it worked